# Support Maldivian language

Tags: html, lang

I'm building a quiz that support 20 languages. 
One is [**Maldivian**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maldivian_language). 
How do I support this. Right now I'm having a bunch of square.
I want to know:
- What font should I use.
- Is there an online translator for English-Maldivian? (google translate do not support this)

Comment: For what it's worth, the Maldivian text on the linked Wikipedia page shows up as a bunch of squares on my system too (Chrome, OS X 10.8). You will probably have to find a custom font and use that.

Comment: Your question doesn't belong here, Ask it in http://superuser.com

Comment: Those texts are fine for me! Win7X64 FF16.

Answer (score 3):

Maldivian uses the Thaana script, which is not very widely supported in fonts. There are two basic strategies: specify a `font-family` rule that lists fonts known to contain Thaana letters, hoping that the user has at least one of them installed, or use a downloadable font with `@font-family`. The latter sounds more realistic in this case. For it, you would need a font that you can legally use that way.

Free fonts that support Thaana include [MPH 2B Damase](http://www.wazu.jp/gallery/views/View_MPH2BDamase.html) and [TITUS Cyberbit](http://titus.uni-frankfurt.de/indexe.htm?/unicode/unitest2.htm) Basic.

For generalities, see my [Guide to using special characters in HTML](http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/html/characters.html).

I would be very surprised at seeing an automatic translator for a small language like Maldivian, and I would also be surprised at seeing an automatic translator that produces decent results when translating a web site.